# Spinner drop down list in toolbar using navigation drawer in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

> Can someone provide me with a link where I can read or watch tutorial?

I am using navigation drawer activity and I want to use **spinner** *drop-down-list*  in second fragment, not fragment which is started when app is launched.

I don't need links for just simple activities.

**UPDATED** I know how to use spinner, but I don't know how to place it in toolbar. I have just one activity, Main Activity, and 4 fragments, I want to place it only in one fragment to use spinner in toolbar

[image]
(image was taken from google, I need same thing)

> I hope you will help me to find valid information

Answer (score 0):

For XML

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bac">

    </Spinner>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In Activity where you want to hide spinner

```
spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I am using Navigation Drawer Activity, and I want to use spinner in toolbar

Comment: Use switch case for spinner items

Comment: I have updated my question, what I need is not how to use spinner.  I don't know how to place it in toolbar

Comment: I have just one activity, Main Activity, and 4 fragments, I want only one of them to use spinner in toolbar